# How to generate an email that follow to email app format?

Tags: java, android, email

```
            gen_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
            String to = text.getText().toString().trim();
            String subject = text2.getText().toString().trim();
            String content = text3.getText().toString().trim();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            buffer.append(to);
            buffer.append(subject);
            buffer.append(content);

            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{to});
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content);
            email.setType("message/rfc822");
            startActivity(email);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, ""));

            MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();

            try {
                BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(email.getAction(), BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 250, 250);
                BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
                Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            catch (WriterException e){
              e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
});
```

i already insert the email intent into my activity but the email that i generated are not follow the email format. is there any way to make my strings triggered to email apps format? please help thank you.

Comment: Java != Javascript

Comment: what do you mean by `not follow the email format`

Comment: the email apps format contain recipient, subject and body, but my string which is 'to,subject,content' are not triggered to the email apps format.

Comment: You mean the values are not being populated?

Comment: yes thats it, i already using try using send email button it worked, but not worked for generator. seems like i am missing some code.